# Does sql config manager changes (example: service account) on 1 FCI node auto update it onto the other node?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, failover-cluster-instance

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/always-on-failover-cluster-instances-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#FCIelements

> Each node in the resource group maintains a synchronized copy of the
> configuration settings and check-pointed registry keys to ensure full
> functionality of the FCI after a failover

My understanding is that service account and other sql config manager settings are stored in the registry.

Does the above quote imply that when any sql config manager change is made on 1 FCI node (sql server service account, sql agent service account, sql integration services service account, protocol changes [tcp/shared memory]) then it will auto apply this on the node 2?

For example: following link suggests that password change made on 1 node gets communicated on other nodes:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/failover-cluster-instance-administration-and-maintenance?view=sql-server-ver15#changing-service-accounts

> You should not change passwords for any of the SQL Server service
> accounts when an FCI node is down or offline. If you must do this, you
> must reset the password again by using SQL Server Configuration
> Manager when all nodes are back online.